# Jest - Cannot find module 'react-hot-loader'

Tags: jestjs, react-hot-loader

I have written an integration test using Jest:

```
import 'jest-styled-components';
import React from 'react';
import { remAuto } from 'tidee-life-theme';
test('blah', () => {});
```

and am getting this strange output:

```
 Cannot find module 'react-hot-loader' from 'core.js'

       7 | const core = {
       8 |     'background-color': '#fff',
    >  9 |     'color': fontColor,
         |                                                      ^
      10 |     'font-family': fontFamily,
      11 |     'font-family-bold': fontFamilyBold,
      12 |     'font-size': fontSize,

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:221:17)
      at ../tidee-life-theme/src/core.js:9:91
      at Object.<anonymous> (../tidee-life-theme/src/core.js:11:3)
```

When I look at `core.js`, there is no reference to `react-hot-loader`:

```
export const fontColor = "#666";
export const fontFamily = `'open_sansregular', helvetica, arial`;
export const fontFamilyBold = `'open_sansbold', helvetica, arial`;
export const fontSize = 13;
export const fontLineHeight = 17 /13;

const core = {
    'background-color': '#fff',
    'color': fontColor,
    'font-family': fontFamily,
    'font-family-bold': fontFamilyBold,
    'font-size': fontSize,
    'line-height': fontLineHeight,
};

export default core;
```

I am using lerna and `tidee-life-theme` is in a package adjacent to the one the test is being run in.
So, what on earth is going on here?

Comment: Are you importing your hot-reload wrapped component into your test ?

Comment: No, I am not. I have not gotten around to importing any components at all yet. The `utils.js` file that I am importing simply contains helper functions for styled-components.

Comment: Check for special characters in core.js. Your issue is a real mystery.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have checked and there are no special chars.

Answer (score 0):

React-Hot-Loader has a babel plugin, which would add `require('react-hot-loader')` to the every file. So - even if you can not see it - it might be there.

Solution - disable react-hot-loader plugin for jest (or enable only for web).

There are different ways to do it. The easiest one - add it via `babel-loader` configurations options in your webpack.conf, and remove from `.babelrc`.

Comment: Is there any documentation for doing this? I removed `'react-hot-loader/babel'` from the `plugins` section of `babel.config.js`, but I'm not sure what to do in my webpack config files?